# Java Interface Design for Multidimensional Matrices

Tags: java, interface, api-design

I am writing classes to represent multidimensional matrices, for example `Matrix2D`, `Matrix3D` and `Matrix4D`. However I would like them to use a common interface called `Matrix`.

Say if there is a method to get an element at a specific index called `get`, for the 2D version it would be of the form `[some return type] get(int i, int j)` whereas the 3D version would be `[some return type] get(int i, int j, ink k)`. What would be the best way to deal with this in an interface? My current thoughts are to either use a class to represent the indices and pass this to the method or have the method accept variable arguments.

**Update:**

I don't need to perform any matrix operations, I just need to store data in multidimensional form and retreive/update values at particular indices. There are other fields (irrelevant to the question) which mean that I have to use classes.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is varargs: `get(int... i)`. Is this not sufficient?

Comment: Seems kind of a strange thing to want to do. The users of your Matrix interface would still need to know whether they're dealing with a 2D or 3D matrix. And most binary Matrix operations (addition, multiplication) require specific relationships between the 2 operands. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @sisyphus I've updated the question to clarify the use of the class.

Comment: If you're passing in parameters, especially multiple parameters, it it gives the perception that logic is being done.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using variable arguments. Maybe an interface method like this would help?

```
public interface Matrix {
    public ReturnType get(int...nums);
}
```

And then, as an example:

```
public class Matrix3D implements Matrix {
    @Override
    public ReturnType get(int...nums) {
        //Consider an exception here
        return get3D(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2]);
    }

    public ReturnType get3D(int i, int j, int k) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I would consider carefully whether you really need this kind of structure or not. If you feel you do, consider adding an exception to the signature of `get` which would throw that exception if the argument list isn't long enough in that class's particular implementation.

Comment: The intention is probably to do stuff directly, not calling another method like `get3D`, although, it doesn't really matter I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably pass in a Point object, representing a single point in X dimensions, in as a parameter and use generics to be specific about the param type.  For example:

Interface

```
public interface Point {
}
```

1D Point (has only the x variable)

```
public class Point1D implements Point {
    private final int x;

    public Point1D(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

2D Point (has the x and y variable)

```
public class Point2D extends Point1D {
    private final int y;

    public Point2D(int x, int y) {
        super(x);
        this.y=y;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

3D Point (has the x, y, and z variables)

```
public class Point3D extends Point2D {
    private final int z;

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

}
```

Matrix Interface (has the point generic on the interface)

```
public interface Matrix <P extends Point> {
    ReturnType get(P point);
}
```

3D Matrix (explicitly uses the 3D point)

```
public class Matrix3D implements Matrix<Point3D> {

    public ReturnType get(Point3D point) {
       // logic
    }

}
```

This would allow you to pass in a 3D Point into a 2D matrix but not a 2D point into a 3D matrix.